# Cannot see Automotive Intel x86 Atom System Image in SDK manager

Tags: android, automotive

I am running Android Studio Electric Eel 2022.1.1 Patch 2
[image: SDK manager]
I cannot see the "Automotive Intel x86 Atom System Image" option as is shown here:
https://developer.android.com/training/cars/testing#system-images

I have tried these steps:

1. Ctrl+Shift+A open the Find Action search box Search System Settings System Settings > Updates SDK Manager > SDK Platforms > Check Show Package Details box

Any idea why I cannot see this option? I want to run an Android Automotive OS AVD to test apps.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this issue?

Comment: Nope, I have looked everywhere, no one seems to address this.